# Haskell complexity of an algorithm

Tags: haskell

I encounter a simple problem on Codeforces, the problem is [this](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1915/E). The thing I wanted to discuss is not about the problem, it about the languages we used, in this case, Python3 and Haskell.

In details, I have 2 version of my algorithm, one in Haskell and the other in Python3. Both of them in Functional programming style. The code looks like this

**Python3**

```py
from operator import add
from itertools import accumulate
from functools import reduce
 
 
def floss(l):
    def e(u):
        a, b = u
        return b if a % 2 == 1 else -b
 
    return map(e, enumerate(l))
 
 
def flock(l):
    return accumulate(l, add)
 
 
def search(l):
    b = zip(l, l[1:])
 
    def equal(u):
        x, y = u
        return x == y
 
    c = any(map(equal, b))
    return 'YES\n' if c else 'NO\n'
 
 
def main():
    t = int(input())
 
    def solution(x):
        return search(sorted(list(flock(floss(x)))))
 
    def get():
        _ = input()
        b = [0] + [int(x) for x in input().split()]
        return b
 
    all_data = [get() for _ in range(t)]
    all_solution = map(solution, all_data)
    print(reduce(add, all_solution))
 
 
main()
```

**Haskell**

```
module Main (main) where
import Data.List (sort)
 
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- des
  putStrLn x
 
readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = fmap (map read.words) getLine
 
flock :: [Int] -> [Int]
flock l = scanr (+) 0 l 
  
floss :: [Int] -> [Int]
floss l = map (e :: (Int, Int) -> Int) $ zip [0..] l where {
  e (u, v) = if mod u 2 == 0 then v else -v
  }
  
search :: [Int] -> String 
search l = if c then "YES\n" else "NO\n" where {
  b = zip l $ tail l;
  c = any (\(x, y) -> x == y) b;
  }
  
solution :: [Int] -> String 
solution = search.sort.flock.floss
 
des :: IO String
des = do 
  io <- readInts
  let t = head io
  all_data <- sequence $ replicate t $ do
    _ <- readInts
    b <- readInts
    return b
  let all_solution = map solution all_data
  let output = foldr (++) "" all_solution
  return output
```

Both of them relatively the same in term of algorithm. In fact, the Python3 passed the testcases with high complexity while Haskell code cannot. I wonder why my code in Haskell run slower than Python3 and I wanted to know the operation of Haskell that make the fault. One thing I found suspicious is the memory usage of my Haskell code is incredibly higher (2-8 times) than Python3 code.

I have just started study about FP recently, so there maybe some mistake that I made in the post.

Update #1: One thing that I found might be useful for bug detecting is that in the Haskell code is `let output = foldr (++) "" all_solution`. In a much worse code, I used `foldl` rather than `foldr`, which made the code extremely slow. I think that might make bug detecting task a little easier.

Comment: des should not exist to be identical to the python, still reading, might answer.
I don't have working GHC because url blocked

Comment: `foldl` builds up a long chain of thunks that don't get evaluated until the very end. Use `foldl'` instead to force evaluation over the course of the iteration.

Comment: @chepner `foldl'` works great when the result is a simple type like `Int`, but it does not help much when the result is a list like in the OP's case (where it's a string).

Comment: @chi You're assuming I actually looked at this wall of code, rather than catching a reference to using `foldl` in place of `foldr` in the last sentence :)

Comment: The memory usage likely has a simple explanation: Haskell's `String` type is extremely inefficient, it's a list of 64-bit pointers to 64-bit values representing UTF-32 characters. It has for years been recommended to use [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.1/docs/Data-Text.html) instead of string unless you need lazy character-by-character processing. However, I would (both in Python and Haskell) not ever generate a list of strings at all, these should be booleans and only in the very end for printing interpreted as `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: You don't need to pass `add` to `accumulate` in python. By default, `accumulate` already adds stuff.

Comment: Also, instead of defining your own `equal` function, and then calling `map(equal, b)`, you can do `from itertools import starmap; from operator import eq` and then `starmap(eq, b)`. Also instead of `b = zip(l, l[1:])`, in python>=3.10 you can do `from itertools import pairwise; b = pairwise(l)`. Putting all this together you can write either `c = any(starmap(eq, pairwise(l)))`... or you can note that `map` can be used directly to operate on more than one iterable, so that you can write directly `c = any(map(eq, l, l[:1]))`

Comment: Looks similar to [this other problem](https://old.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1am45r2/how_to_sort_a_list_of_ints_fast/). (1) the time limit of this site is tailored to C++ solutions (2) list manipulations in Haskell have significant overhead, especially sorting.

Comment: Some stylistic comments, unrelated to your problem. When in `IO`, prefer `readIO` over `read` for its better exception behavior: `fmap (map read . words) getLine` -> `mapM readIO . words =<< getLine`. You frequently `zip` to make tuples, then iterate and unpack the tuples; consider `zipWith` instead: `map (\(u, v) -> ...) $ zip [0..] l` -> `zipWith (\u v -> ...) [0..] l` and `any (\(x, y) -> x == y) (zip l $ tail l)` -> `or (zipWith (==) l (tail l))`. For the first one, even better would be to drop the mod calculation, `zipWith ($) (cycle [id, negate]) l`. 1/?

Comment: Your use of `sequence` and `replicate` has a well-known name: `sequence $ replicate t $ act` -> `replicateM t act`. Your use of `foldr` has a well-known name: `foldr (++) ""` -> `concat`; and then again your use of `map` and `concat` has a well-known name: `concat (map solution all_data)` -> `concatMap solution all_data`. The monad laws let you simplify the nested `IO` block in `des`: `do { _ <- readInts; b <- readInts; return b }` -> `do { _ <- readInts; readInts }` or even better `readInts >> readInts`. I would be tempted to un-`do` your `main`, writing `main = des >>= putStrLn`. 2/2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From profiling, it looks like most of the time is being spent in `readInts`. A really stupid reimplementation that doesn't invoke the full overhead of `read` already triples the speed of the program in my tests:

```
readIntDumb :: String -> IO Int
readIntDumb = go 0 1 where
    go n sgn [] = pure (sgn * n)
    go n sgn (c:cs) = case c of
        '-' -> go n (negate sgn) cs
        d | '0' <= d && d <= '9' -> go (10*n + fromEnum d - fromEnum '0') sgn cs
        _ -> fail "whoops"
```

Moving to `ByteString`-based `IO` gets another factor of two:

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS8

readIntsBS :: ByteString -> [Int]
readIntsBS bs = case BS8.readInt bs of
    Nothing -> []
    Just (n, bs') -> n : readIntsBS (BS8.dropWhile isSpace bs')

readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = readIntsBS <$> BS8.getLine
```

At this point, profiling reveals that about half the runtime is due to `sort`. Switching to [nubInt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.7/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubInt) speeds that step up a lot:

```
import Data.Containers.ListUtils
search l = if nubInt l /= l then "YES" else "NO"
solution = search.flock.floss
```

Or you could implement a custom uniqueness check, though this gets only a small savings over using `nubInt`:

```
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS

search :: [Int] -> String 
search l = if uniqInt l then "NO" else "YES"

uniqInt :: [Int] -> Bool
uniqInt = go IS.empty where
    go seen [] = True
    go seen (n:ns) = case IS.alterF (,True) n seen of
        (False, seen') -> go seen' ns
        _ -> False
```

You'll also want to switch over from `scanr` to `scanl`. (As a rule of thumb, for folds you generally are choosing from `foldr` and `foldl'` based on what operation you're folding, but for scans you almost always want `scanl` or a minor variant of it like `scanl1`.) This almost doubles the speed.

```
flock = scanl (+) 0
```

At this point, the cumulative savings have dropped the runtime on my machine+test file from 25s to 0.8s; perhaps this is going far enough. Here's the complete final result, with a few minor tweaks (for style, not performance) not explicitly discussed above.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bool
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import Data.Char
import Data.Containers.ListUtils
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS8
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS

main :: IO ()
main = do
    t <- readLn
    replicateM_ t $ do
        BS8.getLine
        putStrLn . solution . readIntsBS =<< BS8.getLine

solution :: [Int] -> String
solution = bool "YES" "NO" . uniqInt . scanl (+) 0 . zipWith ($) (cycle [id, negate])

readIntsBS :: ByteString -> [Int]
readIntsBS bs = case BS8.readInt bs of
    Nothing -> []
    Just (n, bs') -> n : readIntsBS (BS8.dropWhile isSpace bs')

uniqInt :: [Int] -> Bool
uniqInt = go IS.empty where
    go seen [] = True
    go seen (n:ns) = case IS.alterF (,True) n seen of
        (False, seen') -> go seen' ns
        _ -> False
```

Comment: could you please also point out which profiling (tool) have you used / how you did the profiling

Comment: @AlexSchell The GHC compiler has the option to do that. In Haskell tool stack command, you add `--profile` in addition for stack argument, and `--profile +RTS -p -hc` for program argument. That should generate a text file that is the thing that we want. The command look like `stack.exe build --exec "HaskellStack-exe --profile +RTS -p -hc" --profile`

Comment: @AlexSchell Yes, more or less exactly as Khang Truong said. Though I was invoking GHC directly, so for me the commands were `ghc -O2 -prof -fprof-auto test && ./test +RTS -p`.